# 'serializationLength' but non-virtual destructor with custom message

Tags: ros, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created a ros node that is a subscriber and publisher. I have also created a message type called "patd" which has the following types:
int32 distance
String Pattern_no

after doing rosmake the custom message class is created and I have done the include accordingly, "depth_viewer/patd.h".

my problem is that when ever I try to use the custom message I get an error when running the node, "segmentation fault" as i'm working with the kinect.

this is the error I get regarding my custom message:

Class '[C@254fb0' has virtual method 'serializationLength' but non-virtual destructor

please have a look at this screenshot http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v67/maltenrazer/roserror.jpg

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33050/%27serializationlength%27-but-non-virtual-destructor-with-custom-message/) by [Maltenrazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2265/maltenrazer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2012-05-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

nvm...fixed now.... the problem was something completely different.

---

Originally posted by [Maltenrazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2265/maltenrazer/) with karma: 36 on 2012-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0